# Ruby api errors in console - How to visualize in a better way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, google-chrome

Alright, kinda a weird question. But I'm gettis some random errors after I call a Ruby Api using AngularJs, as a response I get a big error in the console. Looks like the regular Ruby  error screen but I would like to know if there is a better way to look at it.

Example>
[image]

Sorry if this is not the way to ask.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it's a rails problem, it should be in the console log (or you could use something like airbrake). That being said, this seems like an AngularJs issue. I suspect your question would benefit from that tag...

Answer (score 0):

Redo the request while the `Network` tab is open in Developers Tool. Click this request, i.e `http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in.json`,and then you can preview it on the right.